# Error with Rack fetching session-based cookie

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, thin

My web app is using Rack 1.4.0, Sinatra v1.2.6, Thin v1.2.11, Ruby v1.9.2p180

Navigating to a page I get this error in the log:

```
TypeError - can't convert nil into String:
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb:152:in `hexdigest'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb:152:in `generate_hmac'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb:109:in `unpacked_cookie_data'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb:99:in `extract_session_id'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:43:in `load_session_id!'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:32:in `[]'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:262:in `current_session_id'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:268:in `session_exists?'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:107:in `exists?'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:122:in `load_for_read!'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:59:in `[]'
 /var/www/phrogz.net/routes/test.rb:8:in `logged_in?'
```

The code in test.rb line 8 is:

```
session[ :foo ] == "BAR"
```

Any suggestions on what to upgrade/downgrade to fix this?

Comment: does session[:foo] exist? why not session[:foo] && session[:foo] == "BAR"

Comment: @three Same error with that change (as one would hopefully expect); no, that session variable does not exist when the check is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you run into [this issue](https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/299). The fix is in Rack 1.4.1 so simply upgrading should fix it.

Comment: Confirmed; updating Rack to 1.4.1 (`sudo gem update rack`) fixed this problem.